# How to interprete this singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature, singularities

I am calculating the Kretschmann scalar for the Schwartzchild metric. This is the graphic I get:

[image]

Where $R$ is the radial coordinate and $x=\cos(\theta)$.

So, there is the singularity at $R=0$ as it should, but how do I interprete the other singularities for $x=\pm1$?

Comment: This indicates a mistake. The Kretschmann scalar for the Schwarzschild metric is not a function of $\theta$. There is either an algebra mistake or numerical instabilities.

Comment: It’s just $48M^2/r^6$ in geometrical units. How are you calculating it? If you calculated all the components of the Riemann tensor, did you check that the Ricci tensor vanished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Τhe Kretschmann scalar for the Schwarzchild metric is: $K = \cfrac{12C}{r^{6}}$, where $C$ is an integration constant (in this case $C$ represents mass, in the Schwarzchild case you consider a spherically symmetric object in vaccuo doing nothing. You can compute $C$ using the Komar integral, or the Newtonian limit.). If you take the limit $r \rightarrow 
0$ you can see that the scalar goes to infinity. I cannot understand that graph you posted, the Kretschmann scalar does not depend on θ.

Comment: Explicitly relating $C$ to the mass or Schwarzschild radius of the black hole would make this answer more useful.

Comment: $C$ is related to the mass but it doesn’t really “represent mass”. It is proportional to the *square* of the mass.

Comment: Ok then, the Kretschamann scalar after the identification of the integration constant yields: $K = \cfrac{48M^{2}G^{2}}{r^{6}}$

Comment: Yeap you're right. What i meant is that the constants of integration give you information about the physical system. So in this case where one considers a static spherically symmetric object the constant of integration must somehow be related to the mass of the object.

Comment: If you’re going to put in $G$, I recommend also putting in $c$ for consistency. Usually in GR both, or neither, are set to 1.

Comment: If one considers a charged spherically symmetric object(the Reissner-Nordstrom solution) he will end up with two integration constants, one being related to the charge of the object and one being related to the mass of the object.